# Toggle show/hide when select box changes or on load

Tags: jquery

I have a select box that dependant on the select will show/hide certain information.

This works fine (see code).

```
<script>

    jQuery('#options').on('change',function(){

        if(jQuery(this).val()=='rpp'){
            jQuery('.rpp_fields').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.rpp_fields').hide();
        }

        if(jQuery(this).val()=='busway'){
            jQuery('.busway_fields').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.busway_fields').hide();
        }

    });

    </script>
```

I am now trying to get the same code to execute if one of the items is selected on page load.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks,

John

Comment: can you re explain about this? `I am now trying to get the same code to execute if one of the items is selected on page load.`

Comment: If the page loads and a select item is selected (from a form post) then to run the jQuery. For example, if "busway" is selected it will display the <div> for "busway_fields"

Comment: i see  (from a form post)

Comment: your dropdown option is [rpp, busway] or [empty, rpp, busway]?

Comment: It's either rpp or busway.

Answer (score 2):

1) Extract the handler to a named method.  Use that method in the handler, and call it on page load.

```
function something () {}

$(selector).on('event', something);
something();
```

2) Or, use trigger('change') on the end of the event binding.

```
$(selector).on('event', ....).trigger('event');
```

I suggest the first one so you are not creating an unnecessary event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `$(selector).val().change();` at the end of the change function.

Comment: actually i want to post this `$("#options").val('<?php echo $_GET['opt'];?>').change();` but seems you found it by yourself. now i just add info about this. event change will not triggered by set value on an element, because it requires an actual browser event initiated by the user instead of via javascript code. So you need to trigger the event too using `change()` or `trigger('change')`