# Set checkbox to be checked if input value =

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an input and a checkbox. I have managed to change the value in the input on clicking the checkbox, and un clicking etc which works fine.

I'm looking to auto set the checkbox to be checked on page load only if the input value = yes, as this input value is being loaded dynamically via php and may not be yes.

HTML

```
<input type="text" value = "yes" id ="inputId">
<input type="checkbox" id = "yourCheckboxId">
```

JQUERY

```
$('#yourCheckboxId').click(function() {
        if ($('#yourCheckboxId').is(':checked')){
             $('#inputId').val('yes');
        }    
        if (!$('#yourCheckboxId').is(':checked')){
             $('#inputId').val('no');
        }     
});
```

You'll notice that even though the value in the input is set to yes, on page load, the checkbox isn't checked. This is what I have so far, see jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0z9agrw8/1/

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Definitely along the same logic lines:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576449/toggle-show-hide-when-select-box-changes-or-on-load/47576481#47576481

Comment: In PHP, you just need to add the "checked" prop to your checkbox input if the input value is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var input = $('#inputId').val()

if(input === "yes"){
  $("#yourCheckboxId").prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value = "yes" id ="inputId">
<input type="checkbox" id = "yourCheckboxId">
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this on page load:

```
if($('#inputId').val() == 'yes') { 
    $('#yourCheckboxId').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **always** want it to be checked on page load, you can simply add the "checked" attribute

eg

```
<input type="checkbox" id = "yourCheckboxId" checked>
```

If it's more complicated than that, the other answers will work nicely